# OnFirstLocalVideoFrame is not called

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io

I'm working on a video chat made with Unity and Agora SDK, I need to be notified when the first video frame is rendered.
The doc is clear:

OnFirstLocalVideoFrameHandler
*Occurs when the first local video frame is displayed/rendered on the local video view.*

I added the callback to my instance of IRtcEngine and joined a channel, I expect the OnFirstLocalVideoFrame callback is called when the first image is rendered.

Comment: Hi Gigi,  your observation seems true.  Please create a bug ticket from your Agora developer console so the Agora support team can take care of it.